display:none not hiding the empty option in dropdown in IE
I have running Angular 11 application. In the page I have 2 radio buttons and one dropdown. The behavior is that whenever I change the radio button selection, I want to reset dropdown value and show empty value in the dropdown.
Below code is working fine in Chrome. But in IE I can still see empty option in the dropdown. I don't want to show empty option in the dropdown list.
test.component.html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <select [id]="control.Id" [formControlName]="control.Id" [value]="control.Value">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of control.Items">                        
         <option [value]="item.Value">{{item.Key}}</option>
       </ng-container>
       <option hidden disabled value="" style="display:none;"></option>
     </select>
</form>

test.component.ts
this.myForm.controls['City'].valueChanges.subscribe(this.onCityChange.bind(this));

onCityChange()
{
   this.myForm.get['City'].patchValue('');
}


you might try: "style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" (and/or opacity: 0;?)  But why not remove the option altogether?

@browsermator the reason is I want to show dropdown value as empty on radio button switch. if I dont add option as display:none then on radio button switch, the dropdown shows the last selected value even if i patchValue as null or ‘ ‘

see Options with display:none not hidden in IE maybe try this approach: How to hide select options using css in IE?

I'll usually set it to a selection of "None", or "Choose an option"... something like that.  Selecting blank always seems buggy to me.

I did not try in Internet Explorer due to it not being installed, but checked in Edge and it works fine!
Remove the [value] binding, since you can set the default value on the form control itself, no need for value here
The line this.myForm.get['City'].patchValue(''); Seems to be invalid syntax, we can rewrite this!
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <select [id]="control.Id" [formControlName]="control.Id">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of control.Items">                        
            <option [value]="item.Value">{{item.Key}}</option>
          </ng-container>
          <option hidden disabled value="" style="display:none;"></option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button (click)="clear()">clear</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    test: new FormControl('One'),
  });
  control = {
    Id: 'test',
    Value: 'test',
    Items: [
      { Key: '1', Value: 'One' },
      { Key: '2', Value: 'Two' },
      { Key: '3', Value: 'Three' },
    ],
  };

  clear() {
    this.myForm?.get('test')?.patchValue('');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

It works fine in Chrome, Edge, Firefox but still same issue is there in IE. You can switch to IE mode from Edge also

@AsifZaidi I tried internet explorer 11(downloaded), its working there also!
